# CXF client exception: WARNING: Interceptor for {http://admin.ws....thrown exception, unwinding now java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I will really appreciate your help.

I am trying to run the test below (its purpose is to send a request + security header to a remote server).

The request with security header should look like this:
http://s28.postimg.org/ehg8z5f5p/req_AM3.png

I am using CXF for generating objects from WSDL and I am trying to use those objects to send a request + security header (my code is below).

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
Feb 13, 2014 9:19:05 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://myserver.com url}dUser has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.StartBodyInterceptor.handleMessage(StartBodyInterceptor.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.StartBodyInterceptor.handleMessage(StartBodyInterceptor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1704)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1537)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1445)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:660)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
```

My code:

```
public class TestServiceAdmin
{

@Test
public void test1() throws CxfTest, JAXBException, IOException, XMLStreamException 
{       
    Admin_Service service = new Admin_Service();
    Admin port = service.getPort(Admin.class);

    ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://x.x.x.x:8080/some_services");

    Map<String,Object> inProps= new HashMap<String,Object>();        
    Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();      

    //Security header
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "user123");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    // Callback used to retrieve password for given user.
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName());

    //copy from https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();    

    //Out Intercepter
    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssJOutInterceptor = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssJOutInterceptor);

    //in Intercepter
    WSS4JInInterceptor wssJInInterceptor = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssJInInterceptor);


    //this phase is for fill the object for the method we will choose to run
    RequestA aRequest = new RequestA();
    JAXBElement<String> jxbUserName =new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("useName"), String.class, "username");
    RequestA.setUserName(jxbUserName);
    JAXBElement<String> jxbUserStatus =new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("userStatus"), String.class, "userStatus");
    RequestA.setUserStatus(jxbUserStatus);      

    //run the method
    ResponseA dUserResponse = port.dUser(aRequest);
    System.out.println(dUserResponse.getUserStatus() );

}

}


public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, 
    UnsupportedCallbackException {

    WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

    // set the password for our message.
    pc.setPassword("pass2");
}

}
```

Comment: Which version of CXF are you using? Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078726/cxf-client-exception-interceptor-for-xxx-has-thrown-exception-unwinding-now)? The top 3 lines of your stacktrace are matching. In that question, the NPE was because request did not contain `Content-Type` header

Comment: thanks man, but i dont have this info any more.